# how to use onbeforeunload for back button but prevent on form submits and internal page redirects

Tags: javascript, window.onunload

I am trying to display a warning dialogue to the user if the back button is pressed. The following works OK, except I only want this to happen on the back button or reload. not on form submit redirects that occur throughout the application.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
     e.returnValue = 'warning';
}
```

can anyone help with a solution? preferably javascript only, and not jQuery. thanks

Comment: Add an event listener for the `submit` event on your form, and when the form is submitted set a flag indicating that. Check that flag inside of your `beforeunload` callback, and only execute your logic if the form hasn't been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable when you submit the form. Test for the presence of that variable in the `beforeunload` handler, and only set the return value if it has been set.